# GPO not applying to clients on secondary server

Tags: windows-server-2008, gpo

I've been stuck in this for two whole days trying to solve it but to no avail.

I have the following struture:

[image]

And my GPO's are the following:

[image]

What I'm trying to do, which I succeded in doing to my users on the primary server (SVR-1) is remove the shutdown option as seen in the following:

[image]

But when I try to do the same on my clients on the SVR-2 side it does not apply:

[image]

I only create or edit my GPOs in the SVR-1 since it is the Domain controler and I set a replication to the SVR-2. Why aren't the GPO taking any effect on the SVR-2 clients? Am I missing something?